# Prove variance in Uniform distribution (continuous)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I read in wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29), variance is $\frac{1}{12}(b-a)^2$ , can anyone prove or show how can I derive this?

Comment: Today's homework question for me...

Comment: ProofWiki has a detailed proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Continuous_Uniform_Distribution

Answer (score 35, accepted):

By the definition of the variance, $\operatorname{Var} X = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E} X)^2$.

Since here $\mathbb{E} X = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{[a,b]}x dx = \frac{a+b}{2}$, and $\mathbb{E} X^2 = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{[a,b]}x^2 dx = \frac{b^3-a^3}{3(b-a)}=\frac{a^2+ab+b^2}{3}$, it follows that
$$
\operatorname{Var} X = \frac{a^2+ab+b^2}{3} - \frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{4} = \frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{12} =\frac{(b-a)^2}{12} 
$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $U$ uniform on $[-1,1]$. 
Then $X =  \frac{a+b}2 + \frac{b-a}2 U$ (in law) and
$$
Var\  X = \frac{(b-a)^2}4 Var\  U\\
Var \ U = EU^2 =\frac 12 \int_{-1}^1x^2dx = \int_{0}^1x^2dx =  \frac 13\\
Var\  X = \frac{(b-a)^2}{12}
$$

Comment: silly mistake...

Comment: What is justification for EU^2 = (1/2)Integ(-1,1)x^2dx  The limits were changed from (-1/2,1/2) to (1,1) and a multiplier of (1/2) put in front of the whole thing? That is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U\sim \text{Unif}(0, 1)$, then
$$
E(U) = \int_0^1 u\ du = \frac{1}{2}\ \text{and } 
E(U^2) = \int_0^1 u^2 du = \frac{1}{3}.  
$$
So that, $V(U) = E(U^2) - \left[E(U)\right]^2 = 1/12$.

Now let $X \sim \text{Unif}(a, b)$, then $X = a + (b -a)U$. From elementary probability theory, it follows that
$$
V(X) = (b - a)^2V(U) = \frac{(b - a)^2}{12}
$$