# Stuck in a probability question (revolves around expectancy)

Tags: probability

I am stuck in a probability question that revolves around expectancy:

Alice and Bob play a game- Bob chooses randomally a number between 0 and 100 (included) and Alice guesses it. Then Alice pays Bob the square of the gap between her guess and what he chose.

A. What guess Alice should make to minimize the expectancy of the payment

B. How much money does Bob have to pay alice to make the game fair (i.e: to make the expectancy of Alice and Bob gain $0$) if Alice uses the technique from A.

This is what I did:
Random variable $X$- the number that bob chooses.
$X\sim \text{unif}\{0,...,100\}$)

a- Alices guess

$Y=(X-a)^2$

then I proved $E(Y)$ is minimized when $a=E(x)=50$
(hopefully this is correct).

But for B I am stuck-

I said he should pay her the value of $E[Y]$ when $a=50$.

but here I am stuck-

$E((x-a)^2)=E(x^2)-2aE(x)+E(x)^2=E(x^2)-E(x)^2$
(because from A we know $a=E(x)$)

I read online it's var(x) which turns out $100^2/12=833.3333$. Unfortunately we are yet to learn Variance so is there a way to continue from where I stopped here without using Variance?

Thank you!

Comment: Basically you just need to calculate $\mathbb E[X^2]$. Can you see why this is equal to $(1^2+2^2+\dots+100^2)/100$ ?

Comment: @jlammy - there are $101$ possible values including $0$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Thank you very much!
The think is that when I do that I get that E[x^2]=3350 and E[x]^2=50^2=2500 so I get that he has to pay her 850$. However when I used the var equation I got 833.333
Why is this difference? whichone is the correct answer?

Comment: @DR_2001 I believe your answer of $\ \$850\ $ is correct.  *That* is the variance of $\ X\ $. Why do you think that $\ \text{var}(X)\ $ should be $\ \frac{100^2}{12}\ $ instead?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera that's a formula for varaince of uniformly distributed random variable that I found online, but I guess I should stick to definitions. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm guessing the formula you found is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728059/prove-variance-in-uniform-distribution-continuous).  That's the formula for the variance of a *continuous* uniform distribution—that is, the random variable associated with the distribution can assume *any real* value between $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $.  The random variable you're dealing with has a *discrete* distribution, in that it can only take on *integer* values between $\ 0\ $ and $\ 100\ $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not stuck, since you've already got the answer. You've already determined that Alice's guess $\ a=50\ $, and therefore the amount she has to pay Bob is $\ (X-50)^2\ $.  To make the game fair Bob must therefore pay Alice
\begin{align}
E((X-50)^2)&=E(X^2)-E(X)^2\\
&=E(X^2)-2500
\end{align}
Forget about the fact that you haven't yet learned the (essentially trivial) fact that this is called "the variance" of $\ X\ $. What you need to do is calculate $\ E(X^2)\ $, which is, by definition,
\begin{align}
E(X^2)&=\sum_{x=0}^{100}x^2P(X=x)\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^{100}\frac{x^2}{101}\ .
\end{align}
I see from one of your comments that you've already obtained the correct value of $\ 3350\ $ for this sum, and therefore the correct value of $\ 850\ $ for the variance of $\ X\ $.

Comment: Thank you very much!